# Filter Nested Array To Get Value in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to extract `listImages` that have a status of 'Existing` inside of an array. My problem is that it gets its parent array.

**Data**

```
lists = [
  {
    "listID": "1",
    "listImages": [
      {
        "id": "111",
        "status": "Existing"
      },
      {
        "id": "222",
        "status": "Non-Existing"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "listID": "2",
    "listImages": [
      {
        "id": "333",
        "status": "Non-Existing"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Current Code**

```
const images = lists.map((list) => ({
  ...list,
  listImages: (list.listImages?? []).filter(
    ({ status }) => status === "Existing"
  ),
}));
```

**Expected Output**

```
["111"]
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be much helpful as it will return array of objects, whereas you need an array of primitives. I would use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), like: `lists.reduce((acc, {listImages}) => (listImages.forEach(({id, status}) => status === 'Existing' && acc.push(id)), acc), [])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you just want to get the `id`. Simply do `filter` followed by a `map` for each list. If you want to do this process on all lists and merge the arrays to one, use `flatMap`.

```js
lists = [
  {
    "listID": "1",
    "listImages": [
      {
        "id": "111",
        "status": "Existing"
      },
      {
        "id": "222",
        "status": "Non-Existing"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "listID": "2",
    "listImages": [
      {
        "id": "333",
        "status": "Non-Existing"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const images = lists.flatMap( list => list.listImages.filter(image => image.status === "Existing").map(image => image.id));
console.log(images);
```

Comment: Your code will loop unnecessarily twice over each item of each `listImages` array: first time - to find the matching items and second time to extract the `id`. For large number of items that may become a performance issue.

Comment: Just to have an idea of how much you may hurt performance with those unnecessary iterations: https://jsbench.me/dwkwg5eayd/1

Answer (score 0):

Here you have both **imperative** and **declarative** solutions. You can change named functions to arrow functions and make it even a single line but I don't think that we have to follow that ugly coding style where no one **(not even future you)** understands the code.

```js
lists = [
  {
    "listID": "1",
    "listImages": [
      {
        "id": "111",
        "status": "Existing"
      },
      {
        "id": "222",
        "status": "Non-Existing"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "listID": "2",
    "listImages": [
      {
        "id": "333",
        "status": "Non-Existing"
      }
    ]
  }
]

// Imperative solution
const images = [];

lists.forEach(list => {
  list.listImages.forEach(image => {
    if(image.status === 'Existing'){
      images.push(image.id);
    }
  })
});
console.log(images);

// Declarative solution
const data = lists.flatMap(function getAllImages(list){
   return list.listImages;
}).filter(function getExistingImages(image) {
  return image.status === 'Existing';
}).map(function getIds(image){ 
 return image.id
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: `verbosity !== readability`

Comment: You are saying that the reader should read the function body to understand what function is during. I can't agree there